# SASS element \ written in CSS

Tags: css, sass

I am a bit lost with SASS.

I am working on mixin for Fontello, but it uses \ sign to translate codes to icons.

**How I can write this sign from SASS to CSS?**

Example:

I have icons in map:

```
$fontello-icon: (
    facebook-rect: \e800,
    facebook: \e801
);
```

and using this statement to write them down:

```
&:after
  content: '#{map-get($fontello-icon, facebook)}'
```

But css looks like:

```
h1:after {
  content: "\\e801";
```

Instead of this:

```
h1:after {
  content: "\e801";
```

Can somebody help me solve this problem please?

Comment: I'd recommend steering away from sass in favour of scss. Particularly if you are new to it. If you're using some other indented programming language frequently like python, it makes more sense. Save yourself the extra confusion, and keep the stabilisers on.

Comment: Does '#{unquote(..map get stuff...)}' help? Not sure. It seems fontello might actually have encoded the backslash character... (actually, it seems so, as the backslash will only be an escape character for this kind of thing when used in a string - otherwise its assumed you meant anactual backslash)

Comment: @HunterTurner I will give you an update in the morning, when i try it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @somethinghere Hi. By using unquote function i get same result as i wrote. content: '#{unquote(map-get($fontello-icon, facebook))}' goes into: content: "\\e801"; Do you guys think that migrating that function from sass to scss will work? It seems not right for me.

Comment: The issue seems to be that when you insert that value into a string, it will be escaped. The only way to make that work is to actually store your values in strings in the first place, then they will be printed as is...

Comment: @somethinghere can you give me an example please?

Comment: Basically, its like @mark answer below. The reason is: the value stored in your map is _not a unicode string_, its just a collection of basic characters. When you print it as a string it will escape the backslash because it does not know unicode. Strings (surrounded with quotes) _do_ recognise unicode and will not escape. So turn your map values into strings in order to use unicode characters!

Comment: Think am stupid, but can you provide some JS fiddle or any example how to make it? Thank you. Rather make answer for this thread. You all are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to @Mark answer and provide some context, try this code in your compiler:

```
$a: \e801;
$b: '\e801';
@debug $a;
@debug '#{$a}';
@debug $b;
@debug '#{$b}';
```

The output logged will be:

```
/style.scss:3 DEBUG: \e801 // <- Terminal has displayed the escaped `\\` as `\` (as appropriate for a program)
/style.scss:4 DEBUG: \e801 // <- Same as above
/style.scss:5 DEBUG: (A unicode character that I could not copy in)
/style.scss:6 DEBUG: (A unicode character that I could not copy in)
```

The reason is that SASS - or any programming language (apart from Apple's swift if I recall correctly - they can use unicode everywhere) - does not support these unicode characters anywhere else but *inside* strings (and even then it only supports representations and not the actual characters). So when you declare your unicode string without making it a string, it is *assumed* to just be chracters on their own, like the word `sheep` is just `[s,h,e,e,p]` and `\e801` is just `[\,e,8,0,1]` - the output you want is `[\e801]`. So store your unicode in strings is the general idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$fontello-icon: (
  facebook-rect: '\e800',
  facebook: '\e801'
);

&:after {
  content: map-get($fontello-icon, #{facebook});
}
```

Comment: Hi, tried. I will get &:after {content: ""}; from it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved that problem by this....

I was searching and found this article: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/pull/6728 where somebody solved same problem with FontAwsome.

SassMeister here: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3bfad69a4ca6e34909cf

Result is functional.

Whole code here:

Slash Function:

```
@function PrepSlash($value) {
    @return unquote('"\\#{$value}"');
}
```

Map of codes:

```
$fontello-icon: (
    facebook-rect: "e800",
    facebook: "e801"
);
```

Sass code:

```
&:after
    content: PrepSlash(map-get($fontello-icon, facebook))
```

Comment: Just mentioning, but in your case it might be good to just integrate the map-get stuff into the PrepSlash function. On top of that, if you are going to store these as strings anyhow you don't really need the function... But good job digging deeper!

Comment: You helped a lot and give me a direction. I thank you for your help. Your option is valid too and since then your answer is accepted rather than my own.